# Bug on initializing data member

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm debugging awhile and I found out that some of data member's were not initialized as I expected. I put some images here so you can see how I initialized it.

[image: a]

Then after executing some code while debugging w/ breakpoints, I noticed that value changes as if it is not been initialized at all.

[image: b]

I never change the value of those `data members` only in constructor's body. I even try to do this.

```
rect.radius_top_right = 1;
rect.radius_top_left = 1;
rect.radius_bottom_right = 1;
rect.radius_bottom_left = 1;
```

The value changes through this point but when it reaches the function it will be needed, it somewhat return again to its garbage value.

Can you point out what's the problem here?

**Edit:**

I instantiate the `class swcRectangle` in a global scope (outside `main` function) like this.

```
swcRectangle rect;
```

This bug occurs during `swcRectangle::draw()` call.

Comment: Screenshots of code aren't a good idea on SO because images aren't searchable. Please include the relevant code in the body of the question.

Comment: Some other piece of code writes to it, try valgrind if it is available on your platform.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for pointing that out. It's due to memory corruption, arrays exceeding its boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the bug. It is due to **memory corruption** of other `data member`. I define some arrays and I made some **buggy** setter method for it.

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef uchar rgba[4];

uchar color[4 * 4];
rgba border_color_top;
rgba border_color_right;
rgba border_color_bottom;
rgba border_color_left;

void swcRectangle::setOpacity(uchar opacity)
{
    this->opacity = opacity;
    for (int i = 3; i < 3 * 4; i +=4)
    {
        this->color[i] = opacity;
        //I should have use another iterator here, not 'i'
        border_color_top[i] = opacity;
        border_color_right[i] = opacity;
        border_color_bottom[i] = opacity;
        border_color_left[i] = opacity;
    }
}
```

The indices, excluding `this->color[n]`, exceeds the boundary of the array w/c cause the overwriting of other memory address (It should range only `0 - 4`). I'm unaware and lack of knowledge about this thing. Sorry for this SO :(

**Edit:**

This should have been done like this >.<

```
border_color_top[3] = opacity;
border_color_right[3] = opacity;
border_color_bottom[3] = opacity;
border_color_left[3] = opacity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a data breakpoint in visual studio to identify the code that is making changes to your variables:

1. go to the constructor of your class and after initializations stop execution there.
2. There you have to go to breakpoint window and add new data breakpoint (there is a small button labeled `New` in that window) to the address of `radius_top_left` so you will use `&radius_top_left`
3. continue executions and wait for it to happen. Visual studio will stop at the instruction that changes those 4 bytes of memory.

As far as i know you can set a maximum of 4 data breakpoints but this should be enough. Possible causes can be a memory corruption, or you might have an object with uninitialized variables.

Comment: How can I do the `&radius_top_left` or check the memory location off it using Code::Blocks? I have many arrays inside that class hmm...That seems to be memory corruption I think

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Code::Blocks but it should also have memory breakpoints. You should identity just one variable that is corrupted and focus on that one until you find the problem. Without memory breakpoints you would have to identify the location manually by settings up sanity checks for one member to narrow down the locatino of the corruption.